# $S^3$ is Parallelisable

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-spaces, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, tangent-spaces

My homework asked me to show that $S^3$ is parallelisable. Like in the $S^1$ or $T^n$ cases, I started by parametrising $S^3$ and finding a spanning set for the tangent space at each point, hoping I will discover three spanning vectors that are everywhere linearly independent.

Take a smooth curve $\alpha :(-\epsilon, \epsilon) \to S^3$ with $\alpha(0) = p$. We may parametrise it by $\alpha(t) = (cos(\theta)cos(\phi)cos(\varphi),sin(\theta)cos(\phi)cos(\varphi),sin(\phi)cos(\varphi),sin(\varphi))$ where $\theta, \phi, \varphi : (-\epsilon, \epsilon) \to \mathbb R$. Using this parametrisation, $$T_pS^3 = span\{cos(\theta)cos(\phi)sin(\varphi)\partial_1 + sin(\theta)cos(\phi)sin(\varphi)\partial_2 + sin(\phi)sin(\varphi)\partial_3 - cos(\varphi)\partial_4, \\ cos(\theta)sin(\phi)cos(\varphi)\partial_1 + sin(\theta)sin(\phi)cos(\varphi)\partial_2 - cos(\phi)cos(\varphi)\partial_3, \\ sin(\theta)cos(\phi)cos(\varphi)\partial_1 - cos(\theta)cos(\phi)cos(\varphi)\partial_2\}$$

with $\theta, \phi, \varphi$ evaluated at $0$.

For any $p \in S^3$, the tangent space is a three-dimensional vector space. But when $cos(\phi) = 0$, we see that the third spanning vector vanishes. Hence, at such a point $p$, is the tangent space spanned by only two vectors? This is a contradiction and I don't know what went wrong.

A similar problem arises on $S^2$. If we construct a spanning set as above and it is indeed true that the two spanning vectors are everywhere linearly independent, doesn't that imply that $S^2$ is parallelisable (which it isn't)?

By now I know how to show that $S^3$ is parallelisable, but I can't get my head around what is wrong with arguing like above.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you know the quaternions?

Comment: Generalized polar coordinates are singular, so they're not a suitable tool to see $S^3$ is parallelizable. You can probably find three orthonormal vector fields explicitly by fiddling with signs and permutations of $(w, x, y, z)$, but Pascual's comment leads to a more conceptual approach.

Comment: @PascualLucas, yes I know how the problem is solved using the quaternions. I'm really just trying to understand why polar coordinates don't work.

Comment: @Lollo231000 Polar coordinates are not global, and the frame induced by them does not extend smoothly to a global frame (they are badly behaved near the poles). This is why it's difficult to make global statements using polar coordinates: given the coordinate representation of (e.g.) a vector field, it can be hard to tell if it extends smoothly to a global one. It's much simpler to work with a global construction of $S^3$, such as the embedding in $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: If polar coordinates worked here, wouldn’t they work even easier on $S^2$?